# How can I use a decorator to modify the type of *args?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, decorator, metaclass

I would like to use a `@decorator` to allow me to be able to access `' - '.join(args)` as `args`, as depicted below. Is this possible, using a metaclass perhaps?

```
def a(*args):
    print(args)
a(1, 2, 3)
# (1, 2, 3)

@magic
def b(*args):
    print(args)
b(1, 2, 3)
# 1 - 2 - 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get close:

```
def magic(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        return func(' - '.join(map(str, args)))
    return wrapper
```

but this prints out `('1 - 2 - 3',)` because the body of `b` sees `args` as a tuple due to the `*args`, and I doubt a decorator can get around that. What do you expect to happen if the body is something like `print(args[1])`?

Comment: This is what I want, but the important part for me is getting around `args` being a tuple. Would it be possible to use a metaclass to change this functionality?

Comment: The body shouldn't typically index `args` - it will expect it to be a string. (If it did, however, `args[1]` would return the second character in the string.)

Comment: This isn't your first question where you've asked for some pretty weird stuff. This is likely to lead to buggy and confusing code. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm testing to see if something works. It's not something to use in general, but it would be helpful to include in a set of child classes I'm designing. I'm also quite curious as to whether or not this is possible.

Comment: If you really want to do this then you probably have to modify the source code. Consider the ast module.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So part of the problem is that you're using integers where you need strings, so convert them into strings and then use the join function.

```
def magic(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        return ' - '.join(map(str, args))
    return wrapper

@magic
def a(*args):
    return 'Arguments were {}.'.format(args)

print(a(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: Although that does work, it's not what I'm asking for. I want that functionality in a decorator, and then the ability to access `args` as the string `"1 - 2 - 3"` (rather than a tuple) in the function itself.

Comment: This does work, but it never actually executes `a`. The output displays `1 - 2 - 3`, but it never shows `Arguments were 1 - 2 - 3`. In the `magic` decorator declaration, `func()` is never called.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, made a mistake with indentation there.